# Run script in tabs in Terminal in High Sierra

Tags: terminal, tabs, applescript, macos-high-sierra

This AppleScript stopped working in High Sierra and returns the error 
"error "Terminal got an error: Can’t get tab 2 of window 1." number -1728 from tab 2 of window 1"

I'm not that good with scripting so any help would be appreciated.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate  
    do script  
    do script "rsync -avCP --progress --stats /Volumes/TERRI1/DCIM/NORMAL/ /Volumes/DCArchive/Vids" in tab 1 of front window  
    my makeTab()
    do script "rsync -avCP --progress --stats /Volumes/TERRI2/DCIM/NORMAL/ /Volumes/DCArchive/Vids" in tab 2 of front window
    my makeTab()
    do script "rsync -avCP --progress --stats /Volumes/TERRI3/DCIM/NORMAL/ /Volumes/DCArchive/Vids" in tab 3 of front window
    my makeTab()
    do script "rsync -avCP --progress --stats /Volumes/TERRI4/DCIM/NORMAL/ /Volumes/DCArchive/Vids" in tab 4 of front window
end tell

on makeTab()
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down} delay 0.2
end makeTab
```

Answer (score 1):

After much Googling and trial and error this works.

```
tell application "Terminal"
activate
do script
do script "rsync -avCP --progress --stats /Volumes/TERRI1/DCIM/NORMAL/ /Volumes/DCArchive/Vids" in tab 1 of front window
my makeTab()
do script "rsync -avCP --progress --stats /Volumes/TERRI2/DCIM/NORMAL/ /Volumes/DCArchive/Vids" in selected tab of front window
my makeTab()
do script "rsync -avCP --progress --stats /Volumes/TERRI3/DCIM/NORMAL/ /Volumes/DCArchive/Vids" in selected tab of front window
my makeTab()
do script "rsync -avCP --progress --stats /Volumes/TERRI4/DCIM/NORMAL/ /Volumes/DCArchive/Vids" in selected tab of front window
```

end tell

on makeTab()
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    delay 0.2
end makeTab

Comment: Hi Terri! The solutions looks like the problem...!? I compared them for a time and I can't find either the error nor the solution... Can you please enlighten the community and explain the found error and how exactly you solved it? Thanx

Comment: I fixed my post.
This was what needed to be changed.

"of front window"
    CHNAGED TO 
"in selected tab of front window"